# Articles not showing up on front end on a custom made template joomla 3.1

Tags: templates, article, joomla3.1

I have created my own Joomla template using Joomla 3.1. 
I have my main menu with the menu item "home" that leads to the front page. 
I have a module called "body" in which I want my articles to be displayed, depending on which page the user is I want a different article to show up.

The article that I want to show up on the "Home" page is in a category called "home". My menu item "home" is a single article linking to the article I want to be on the front page.

All of the statuses are on published and the access on all mentioned items are public. 
When I open the front end I can see the "body" module but no article. If I try using Protostar there is no problem and the article shows up.

Can anyone help? I suppose it is because there is no link between the "body" module and my article/category...?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: all I needed to do is to add the tag `jdoc:include type="component" /` into my template. After that it worked fine...